# Push the right column

Tags: two-column

What's the way to push to the right the second solumn when using `twocolumn`?

I'm just using

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I've tried `\setlength{\columnsep}{xcm}` but that creates more space between columns and I just want to push the second column a bit to the right.

Comment: If you push the second column to the right and keep the first column in place, the space between them will increase. Do you want to move the whole text block to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This is another solution

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\addtolength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{\columnsep}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Here is a solution: we need to patch `\@outputdblcol` command that output twocolumn pages.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputdblcol{\hfil
        {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}}{\hfil
        \hspace{2cm} % or what you need
        {\normalcolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}}{}{\errmessage{Error in patching \string\@outputdblcol}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that does it. But I'm having lots of badboxes, probably because of the new adjustment.

Comment: @Ustanak see update

Comment: Excellent! That's better!